# Sending a parameter from List to a method which is annotated with @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, modelattribute

I have a list page as shown below and when I click on Edit button, I want to send the patientId to the getObject() so that I can load the object from DB if the patientId exists. I tried in many ways, but its taking null as the patiendId in getObject(). 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Following is my List page ::

```
       <c:forEach var="pat" items="${patients}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>                            
            <c:url var="editUrl" value="/patient/${pat.patientId}"/>

                    <td>${pat.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${pat.mobileNumber1}</td>
                    <td>${pat.emailId1}</td>

               <td><a href='<c:out value="${editUrl}"/>'>Edit</a></td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Controller code::

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/patient")
public class PatientController {

  @ModelAttribute
  public Patient getObject(@RequestParam(required=false) String patientId){

    System.out.println("Model Attribute method :: "+patientId);
    //Here I want to load the object using patientId.
    return(patientId != null ? patientDAO.findPatientById(patientId) : new    Patient());

}

@RequestMapping(value="/{patientId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editPatient(@PathVariable("patientId")String  patientId){
    System.out.println("Editing Id : "+patientId);
    //Able to get the Id here.
    return "editPage";
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Below is my working code. Hope it will help someone.Thanks to all.

```
<tr>                                                        
    <c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/patient/delete/${pat.patientId}"/>

            <td>${pat.firstName}</td>
            <td>${pat.mobileNumber1}</td>
            <td>${pat.emailId1}</td>

        <td><a href="newPatient?patientId=${pat.patientId}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href='<c:out value="${deleteUrl}"/>'>Delete</a></td>

</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller code::

```
@ModelAttribute
public Patient getObject(@RequestParam(value="patientId", required=false) String patientId){
    System.out.println("Model Attribute method :: "+patientId);

    return (patientId != null ? patientDAO.findPatientById(patientId) : new Patient());     
}

@RequestMapping(value="/newPatient", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String demo(ModelMap model){

    System.out.println("Demo of Patient");  

    return "newPatient";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@PathVariable` in one place and `@RequestParam` in another and are are sending a path variable (/patients/123 rather than a request param /patients?patientId=123) : use one or the other.

Updating this as below should work:

```
  @ModelAttribute
  public Patient getObject(@PathVariable(required=false) String patientId){

    System.out.println("Model Attribute method :: "+patientId);
    //Here I want to load the object using patientId.
    return(patientId != null ? patientDAO.findPatientById(patientId) : new    Patient());

}}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, but in my case since many other methods are calling getObject() which dont pass @pathvariable, Can u please assist me how to send the requestParam here from the list.Thank you

Comment: Well why don't you ask a proper question **giving the full facts** and then no one else will waste time trying to answer.

Comment: I din think in that way, Sorry about that :-(